# .Net 6.0 MAUI. On simple code UI getting freeze for a second not getting why

Tags: .net, xaml, .net-6.0, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am new to .net 6.0 MAUI using Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.5.0.
I just wrote simple code to show the Mathematical table of entered number on button click using MVVM. I am displaying the table using CollectionView but it freezes the UI for a second not getting why. I am using CommunityToolkit.

XAML Code is as Below

```
 <Frame Style="{StaticResource FrameBaseStyle}"
           Grid.Row="2" 
           Margin="10,10,10,0" 
           BorderColor="{StaticResource Primary}">
        <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTable}" 
                         ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                         ItemsLayout="VerticleGrid"
                         Margin="10">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BackgroundColor="White" StrokeThickness="0.15">
                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto, 20*,20*,20*,30*" >
                            <Label Text="{Binding TableOf}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource LabelLocalStyle}"/>
                            <Label Text="x" 
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Style="{StaticResource LabelLocalStyle}"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                   FontSize="25"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding MultiplyBy}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="End"
                                   Style="{StaticResource LabelLocalStyle}"
                                   Grid.Column="2"/>
                            <Label Text="=" 
                                   Style="{StaticResource LabelLocalStyle}"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                   FontSize="25"
                                   Grid.Column="3"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                   Style="{StaticResource LabelLocalStyle}"
                                   Text="{Binding Result}" 
                                   Margin="0,0,5,0"
                                   Grid.Column="4"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Frame>
```

calling GetTable() mathod on button click

```
    private async void GetTable()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => CreateTable());
    }

    private void CreateTable()
    {
        List<Table> finalTable = new List<Table>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Table table = new Table();
            table.TableOf = TableOf;
            table.MultiplyBy = i;
            table.Result = TableOf * i;
            finalTable.Add(table);
        }
        CurrentTable = new ObservableCollection<Table>(finalTable);
    }
```

Comment: I Found that when value gets assigned to ObservableCollection that time the UI gets freeze. Line is 
CurrentTable = new ObservableCollection<Table>(finalTable);
any solution for it ? Can anybody help ?

Comment: Have you ever tried to call the CreateTable() method directly instead of asynchronously?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jianwei Sun - MSFT. I am not calling the CreateTable() method directly instead of async.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define `finalTable`,add item to `CurrentTable`  directlly.

Please refer to the following code:

```
private async void GetTable()
{
    await Task.Run(() => CreateTable());
}

private void CreateTable()
{
    CurrentTable = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    //List<Table> finalTable = new List<Table>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Table table = new Table();
        table.TableOf = TableOf;
        table.MultiplyBy = i;
        table.Result = TableOf * i;
        //finalTable.Add(table);

        // add table to CurrentTable directlly
         CurrentTable.Add(table);
    }
    //CurrentTable = new ObservableCollection<Table>(finalTable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks  Jessie Zhang -MSFT for your reply. But it didn’t work for me.

Comment: Does this problem occur if you don't load your data for your page( for example, comment code  `GetTable()`)?

Comment: If I comment below  code then it works perfectly.

**CurrentTable = new ObservableCollection<Table>(finalTable);**

Comment: It's strange, I added 100 items and didn't get a 1-second stutter. Could you please share a gif to show your problem？

Comment: @
Jessie Zhang -MSFT
    thanks for your reply.  You can find my code here on OneDrive Link.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqBu7nLA3VASj8IbE_3ck_32oAYFAQ?e=KelzNh

Comment: @ Jessie Zhang -MSFT thanks for your reply. 

I made some changes in code and now it's working perfectly but I don't know whether it's the right approach or not. Please share your view. You can find my code here on OneDrive Link.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqBu7nLA3VASj8IbE_3ck_32oAYFAQ?e=KelzNh